# Problems with TcpListener reading data from socket in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am having trouble reading large messages sent to a TcpListener from a TcpClient using BeginReceive / BeginSend in C#.

I have tried to append a four byte length header to my messages, but on occasion I will not receive it as the first packet which is causing problems.

For example, I sent a serialized object that contains the values [204, 22, 0, 0] as the first four bytes of the byte array in my BeginSend.  What I receive on the server in the BeginReceive is [17, 0, 0, 0].  I have checked Wireshark when sending simple strings and the messages are going through, but there's a problem with my code.  Another example, is when I send "A b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" to test I constantly receive "p q r . . . 8 9 0".

I thought that if packets were received out of order or if one was dropped, TCP would handle the resubmission of the lost packets and/or reorder them before sending them up.  This would mean that my first four bytes should always contain my message size in the header.  However, looking at the above examples this isn't the case, or it is and my code is messed up somewhere.

After the code below I just look if it's sending a particular command or type of object then responding based on what was received.

One I have the core functionality in place and get a better understanding of the issue I can begin to refactor, but this really has me at a stand still.

I've been banging my head against a wall for days trying to debug this.  I have read several articles and questions about similar problems, but I haven't found a way to apply the suggested fixes to this particular instance.

Thanks in advance for your assistance with this.

*The YahtzeeClient in the following code is just a wrapper around TcpClient with playerinformation.*

```
    private void ReceiveMessageCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        byte[] response = new byte[0];
        byte[] header = new byte[4];
        YahtzeeClient c = (YahtzeeClient)AR.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            // If the client is connected
            if (c.ClientSocket.Client.Connected)
            {
                int received = c.ClientSocket.Client.EndReceive(AR);

                // If we didn't receive a message or a message has finished sending
                // reset the messageSize to zero to prepare for the next message.
                if (received == 0)
                {
                    messageSize = 0;

                    // Do we need to do anything else here to prepare for a new message?
                    // Clean up buffers?
                }
                else
                {
                    // Temporary buffer to trim any blanks from the message received.
                    byte[] tempBuff;

                    // Hacky way to track if this is the first message in a series of messages.
                    // If messageSize is currently set to 0 then get the new message size.
                    if (messageSize == 0)
                    {
                        tempBuff = new byte[received - 4];

                        // This will store the body of the message on the *first run only*.
                        byte[] body = new byte[received - 4];

                        // Only copy the first four bytes to get the length of the message.
                        Array.Copy(_buffer, header, 4);

                        // Copy the remainder of the message into the body.
                        Array.Copy(_buffer, 4, body, 0, received - 4);

                        messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(header, 0);

                        Array.Copy(body, tempBuff, body.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Since this isn't the first message containing the header packet
                        // we want to copy the entire contents of the byte array.
                        tempBuff = new byte[received];
                        Array.Copy(_buffer, tempBuff, received);
                    }

                    // MessageReceived will store the entire contents of all messages in this tranmission.
                    // If it is an new message then initialize the array.
                    if (messageReceived == null || messageReceived.Length == 0)
                    {
                        Array.Resize(ref messageReceived, 0);
                    }

                    // Store the message in the array.
                    messageReceived = AppendToArray(tempBuff, messageReceived);

                    if (messageReceived.Length < messageSize)
                    {
                        // Begin receiving again to get the rest of the packets for this stream.
                        c.ClientSocket.Client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveMessageCallback, c);
                        // Break out of the function.  We do not want to proceed until we have a complete transmission.
                        return;
                    }

                    // Send it to the console
                    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageReceived);
```

**Marked as resolved.  The solution was to wrap the message in a header and end of message terminator then modify the code to look for these indicators.

The reasoning behind the use of sockets was due to constraints on the project where web services were not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having problems because you don't know the first message size and sometimes you are getting more, sometimes less, sometimes you getting some of what's left in cache...

An easy solution is to ALWAYS send the message size before the actual messages, something like:

[MYHEADER][32 Bit Integer][Message Content]

Lets supose that MYHEADER is ASCII, just an dummy identifier, in this case I would:

1: Try to receive 12 bytes to catch the entire header (MYHEADER + 32Bit Integer) and don't do anything until you do. After that, if the header identifier IS NOT MYHEADER, then I would assume that the message got corrupted and would have something like a reset in the connection.

2: After I confirmed that the header is ok, I would check the 32bit integer for the message size and allocate the necessary buffer. (You might want to limit the memory usage here, something like 6Mb max and if your messages go beyond this, add a index after the 32bit integer to specify the message part...)

3: Try to receive until the message size specified in the header.

Comment: I am sending a four byte header with every message being sent and storing it in the byte[] header.  However, I'm not prefixing that header with something to let me know it is the header so I'll give that a shot.  I thought that TCP guaranteed message order so I assumed the first four bytes should always have my message size. Is this not the case?

Comment: TCP does guarantee but the identifier prevents alignment problems that might happen in subsequent messages, imagine it like this, you try to receive a message, something goes wrong and you only receive part of the message, later you try to receive another message using the same connection, you might get the rest of the old one in cache, this would cause some headaches. Another thing, I really recommend you to use a State Machine, when I read before the "hack away" section, it gave the appearance that you weren't receive the message size the first time.

Comment: messageSize is reset after a full message is read so if it has a value of 0 it's assuming that it's the start of a new message.  This is working for the majority of the messaging (signing in to lobby works, chat msgs are sent properly, and most game state objects are sent) however on occasion I run into the above mentioned issue.  I will focus my attention on the contents of the byte[] when it is being passed into the BeginReceive to see if it's not properly being cleared.  I'm making an assumption that this is what you are referring to when you mention "cache".

Comment: Cache is controlled by the OS, it always write to it first and then send to your app, that's why you might have parts of old messages in there. And as I said, you might want to look into state machines so that your app can detect errors and self correct. It would make the code a way simpler to mantain.

Comment: Can it be force cleared after a message has been received or when an exception occurs?  I'll look into state machines using .net.  Thanks for your assistance with this btw.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You can close the connection and open another one or, in the first state, try to receive anything before you send your message, anything that got stuck in the cache will be received instantly. Also, you are using the asynchronous version of the method, you may want to look at async/await, it might be strange at first, but it makes the code a lot easier, you can write sequential code and it will do the synchronization for you.

Comment: One problem I had in the past that you should be aware of, even thou you get the communication working, things will break, you may want to code the app in a way to allow the message to be resent without duplicating things.

Comment: Marking this response as the answer.  The solution to my problem was modifying a wrapMessage function to return a message with a "header" label and a "end of message" label. Thank you Alexandre for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to have a good understanding of the fact that TCP is a stream of bytes without boundaries. For example your header reading will fail if you get less than 4 bytes in that read.

A very simple way to receive a length prefixed message is using `BinaryReader`:

```
var length = br.ReadInt32();
var data = br.ReadBytes(length);
```

That's all. Make yourself familiar with all the standard BCL IO classes.

Usually it is best not to use sockets at all. Use a higher level protocol. WCF is good.

Comment: I understand the bytes will vary, the case where I receive less than four bytes is an oversight on my part and will need to be handled.  What happens if the first four bytes of the stream don't actually contain the header you expect it to contain?  Won't I run into the same situation explained in the original post? I have tried using NetworkStream and MemoryStream, but it resulted in the same outcome as mentioned above.  The BinaryReader looks promising and I'll look further into it.  I used WCF in the past and wanted to gain an understanding of socket programming.